# Running Django management command on gae

Tags: django, django-models, gcloud

Good day. How do I run

```
py manage.py migrate
```

On my Google app engine instance
And how to run Django admin site after deploying. I've checked the tutorials online and most are not very clear

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

instead of:

```
py manage.py migrate
```